# Retrofit2, java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, rest, retrofit

I have a client application that has to submit Corpse information to the server using Retrofit2, the server side is okay, in my client app however I'm getting an error I don't understand, please help.

Here is my interface

```
public interface CorpseServiceInterface {
    @Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("corpses")
    Call<Corpse> save(@Body Corpse player);
}
```

And bellow is the implementation

```
public class CorpseService {

    private CorpseServiceInterface server;

    public CorpseService(DAO<Corpse> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
                .create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API.API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        server = retrofit.create(CorpseServiceInterface.class);
    }

    public void save(Corpse corpse) {
        Call<Corpse> call = server.save(corpse);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Corpse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Corpse> call, Response<Corpse> response) {
                System.out.println("Success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Corpse> call, Throwable t) {
                Request request = call.request();
                System.out.println("Request Url: " + request.url());
                System.out.println("onFailure: " + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.request(OkHttpCall.java:63)
at lfs.mortuary.CorpseService$1.onFailure(CorpseService.java:59)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:99)
at lfs.mortuary.CorpseService.save(CorpseService.java:50)
at lfs.common.DAO.save(DAO.java:54)
at fastfx.view.InputFormDialog.saveOrUpdate(InputFormDialog.java:155)
at fastfx.view.InputFormDialog.lambda$0(InputFormDialog.java:131)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
```

Comment: The Error is thrown in the `retrofit2.OkHttpCall` class at line 63. Put a debug breakpoint there so you can inspect the original StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StackOverflowError is a Throwable, but it is an Error and not an Exception.

Within Java, Exceptions typically are items one can recover from and have the JVM perform more processing.  Errors are generally non-recoverable and the JVM cannot continue processing.

You need to investigate the source of this Error and fix it.  Odds are there is some recursive call that is not going to exit from creating new calls to itself, or something similar.

You won't be able to cast this Error into a RuntimeException, because it isn't a RuntimeException, or even an Exception.  It is an Error.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, the problem was not with Retrofit but the problem was that I had a circular reference on my `Corpse` class so GSON was unable to serialize the `Corpse` object.

Using the `@Expose` annotation on parent property in child class solve it